# Extracting Information from Haskell Object

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I'm confused on how to get values out of function results. In my particular case, I am trying to parse Haskell files and see which AST nodes appear on which lines. This is the code I have so far:

```
import Language.Haskell.Parser
import Language.Haskell.Syntax

getTree :: String -> IO (ParseResult HsModule)
getTree path = do
               file <- readFile path
               let tree = parseModuleWithMode (ParseMode path) file
               return tree

main :: IO ()
main = do
       tree <- getTree "ex.hs"
       -- <do something with the tree other than print it>
       print tree
```

So on the line where I have the comment, I have a syntax tree as `tree`. It appears to have type `ParseResult HsModule`. What I want is just `HsModule`. I guess what I'm looking for is a function as follows:

```
extract :: ParseResult a -> a
```

Or better yet, a general Haskell function

```
extract :: AnyType a -> a
```

Maybe I'm missing a major concept about Haskell here?

p.s. I understand that thinking of these things as "Objects" and trying to access "Fields" from them is wrong, but I'd like an explanation of how to deal with this type of thing in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of [`ParseResult`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-1.0.2.0/docs/Language-Haskell-ParseMonad.html#t:ParseResult) is:

```
data ParseResult a = ParseOk a | ParseFailed SrcLoc String
```

(obtained from source code)

So there are two possibilities: either the parsing succeeded, and it will return a `ParseOk` instance, or something went wrong during the parsing in which case you get the location of the error, and an error message with a `ParseFailed` constructor.

So you can define a function:

```
getData :: ParseResult a -> a
getData (ParseOk x) = x
getData (ParseFailed _ s) = error s
```

It is better to then throw an error as well, since it is always possible that your compiler/interpreter/analyzer/... parses a Haskell program containing syntax errors.

Comment: `getData` is bogus. Bailing with `error` is the wrong way to handle a parse error.

Answer (score 7):

Looking for a general function of type

```
extract :: AnyType a -> a
```

does indeed show a big misunderstanding about Haskell. Consider the many things `AnyType` might be, and how you might extract exactly one object from it. What about `Maybe Int`? You can easily enough convert `Just 5` to `5`, but what number should you return for `Nothing`?

Or what if `AnyType` is `[]`, so that you have `[String]`? What should be the result of

```
extract ["help", "i'm", "trapped"]
```

or of

```
extract []
```

?

`ParseResult` has a similar "problem", in that it uses `ParseOk` to contain results indicating that everything was fine, and `ParseFailed` to indicate an error. Your incomplete pattern match successfully gets the result if the parse succeeded, but will crash your program if in fact the parse failed. By using `ParseResult`, Haskell is encouraging you to consider what you should do if the code you are analyzing did not parse correctly, rather than to just blithely assume it will come out fine.

Comment: That makes sense. What I wasn't understanding is that `ParseResult` has 2 _and only 2_ possible values: `ParseOk` and `ParseFailed`, which are wrapped around the actual value (`HsModule` in the success case and `SrcLoc` & `String` in the failure case).

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out how to do this. It seems that when I was trying to define

```
extract :: ParseResult a -> a
extract (ParseResult a) = a
```

I actually needed to use

```
extract :: ParseResult a -> a
extract (ParseOk a) = a
```

instead. I'm not 100% sure why this is.

Comment: Never forget to turn on warnings: they will point out that you forgot to handle the `ParseFailed` case. Having two possible outcomes (success and failure) is the whole point of `ParseResult`.

Comment: That is because `ParseResult a` is a type. Pattern matching only accepts patterns on a value level. That's why you have to match your parameter to a data constructor. It is comparable to `Maybe`. To extract a value from a value of type `Maybe a`, you have to match it to `Just`, not to `Maybe`, that wouldn't make sense.